# unload nfsd - Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged

Tags: macos, launchd

While I was trying to unload my `nfsd` instance I found out that I cannot do it anymore.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
```

This behaviour was [introduced with the Mac OS Sierra update 10.12.4](https://clburlison.com/10.12.4-locationd/).

How can I enable/disable the nfsd daemon?

Should I disable the System Integrity Protection, stop/start the service and enable the System Integrity Protection every time? And, if yes, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to disable the "System Integration Protection":

[How to Disable System Integrity Protection](https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/)

And now, you'll be able to disable your "Notification Center":

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
```

And then, kill the current instance of "Notification Center":

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

When you reboot, isn't necessary to do that anymore...

I hope I've helped

PS: Don't forget, at this point your root user will have all permissions. I recommend to reboot into recovery mode one more time to enable your System Integration Protection:

```
csrutil enable
```

Comment: Not sure if I have understood your answer. My question was about how to disable `nfsd` aka [network file system daemon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), so what's Notifications Center?

Comment: Tried same with unloading RCD, but after enabling protection back - it become loaded again.

Comment: @extempl Same experience. I created a separate question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421674/disabling-notification-center-in-macos-big-sur-11-4).